# How can I force the SimpleXML to ignore HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, simplexml

I try to start using xml parsing via SimpleXML. And I can not find how to do a basic thing:
I have XML file that contains HTML tags, like this:

```
<root>
<title>some text</title>
<content>some <span>text</span></content>
</root>
```

So I need to parse only xml tags like `root` `title` `content` and to ignore html tags like `span`. Also I need to ignore things like `&nbsp`. 
I'm sure there is a simple way to do it. But could not find how to do it.

Comment: `title` is also quite normal HTML tag.

Comment: So, can I define the tags that I want to parse? Say, I want to parse only certain predefind tags.

Comment: If you just want to ignore the tags and not their content - you could use a simple string match to remove them in the string before you parse it. `str_replace(array('<span>','</span>'),array('',''),$xmlstring);`

Comment: @Mikey The problem is that i have very very big file with a lot of html tags. So I think that the better way is to define the XML tags that I want to parse (if it is possible)

Comment: str_replace can handle a crazy amount of replacements/second - give it a try. Also I'm 90% sure you can't do that using SimpleXML.

Comment: The speed is not a problem... The problem is that I have a lot of difernt html tags, and a lot of them with attributes like `<span id="23" style="color:red">`. And besides I do not want exclude the tags completely, but I want to save them like text.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the text of the `content` tag using CDATA.

For example:

```
<root>
  <title>some text</title>
  <content><![CDATA[some <span>text</span>]]></content>
</root>
```

So this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement({the above XML});
echo htmlspecialchars($xml->content);
```

Would produce `some <span>text</span>`. This would also allow the use of such things as `&amp;` and what not.